# Babel Not Working Outside of Main Node.js App

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs

My Express.js server is currently being started by running `start.js`, which in turn runs  `server.js` *(code below)*. For example,

```
nodemon start.js
```

**Problem:** When I try to run the file at `src/lib/seed_database.js` using

```
node seed_database.js
```

we get the errors showing that babel is not transpiling any JS files, such as

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

What is the recommended way to get babel to work on a file other that `server.js`?

**Environment**

- Node 13.7.0
- Mac OS X 10.15.2
- @babel/runtime 7.8.4
- @babel/core 7.8.4
- @babel/plugin-transform-runtime 7.8.3
- @babel/preset-env 7.8.4
- @babel/register 7.8.3"

**Directory Structure**

```
my-app
├── .node_modules
├── src
│   ├── lib
│   │    └── seed_database.js
│   ├── v1
│   │    └── routes.js
│   ├── start.js
│   └── server.js
├── .babelrc
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
```

**start.js**

```
require("@babel/register")({
    presets: [
      ["@babel/preset-env", {
        "targets": {
          "node": "current"
        }
      }]
    ]
});

module.exports = require('./server.js')
```

**server.js**

```
import express from 'express';
import v1ApiRoutes from './v1/routes';
import constants from './config/constants';

const app = express();
app.use('/v1', v1ApiRoutes);

app.listen(constants.PORT, err => {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Cannot run!')
    } else {
        console.log(`App listening on port: ${constants.PORT}`)
    }
});
```

**seed_database.js**

```
const db = require('../../config/db')['appDb'];

...
```

**db.js**

```
...

export const appDb = appDb;
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
    "plugins": [
        ["@babel/transform-runtime"]
    ]  
}
```

---

### Update

Jeremy Harris' suggestion works:

```
require("@babel/register")({
    presets: [
      ["@babel/preset-env", {
        "targets": {
          "node": "current"
        }
      }]
    ]
});

const db = require('../../config/db')['appDb'];
```

However, when we replace the `require` line with named imports:

```
import { appDb as db } from '../../config/db';
```

we now get a new error

> SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

---

### Update #2

Using Jeremy Harris' second suggestion of a single entry point works

```
node start.js seed
```

**start.js**

```
require("@babel/register")({
    presets: [
      ["@babel/preset-env", {
        "targets": {
          "node": "current"
        }
      }]
    ]
});


if (process.argv.indexOf('seed') > -1) {
  module.exports = require('./lib/seed_database.js')
  return
}

 module.exports = require('./server.js')
```

Comment: Try adding `require("@babel/register")` to your seed file.

Comment: @JeremyHarris That works! However, only works if I use `const db = require(...)`. If we were to use named imports, such as `import { appDb as db } from '../../config/db';`, then we now get the error `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`

Comment: Maybe in `start.js`, you check for CLI args and if the argument is "seed" then you include the seeder, otherwise the normal server. That way it's only a single entry point for including babel.

Comment: @JeremyHarris Thanks, now it works! Updated question with the code that works. Is the code written correctly? I find it strange to have 2 `module.exports` and a `return` after the first `module.exports`

Comment: Btw, should the `require("@babel/register")` line also appear in `.bashrc`?

Comment: See my answer. And no, I am not sure why you would put that in bashrc, what does bash have to do with this?

Comment: @JeremyHarris Sorry, I mean `.babelrc`, not `.bashrc`

Comment: See my update in answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we discussed in the comments, the issue is that your seed file was not including the `@babel/register` code, hence it didn't transpile it. Per the suggestion with CLI args, you could modify it to use a single `module.exports` like:

```js
// Default module
let commandModule = './server.js';

// Override with different command
if (process.argv.indexOf('seed') > -1) {
  commandModule = './lib/seed_database.js';
}

module.exports = require(commandModule);
```

If you want to keep configuration in .babelrc, you can do this when including @babel/register:

```js
require('@babel/register')({
  extends: './.babelrc',
  ignore: [/node_modules/],
});
```

This GitHub issue discusses some of the issues around it in case you run into any: https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/8321